# io.LimitReader EOF when reading http.Body

Tags: go

This is probably very obvious to someone, but I need a little help seeing where I am going wrong.
I am trying to limit the data I am reading from an http.Response.Body by using io.LimitReader. I am reading directly into a []byte. However when I try to do this I get an EOF. Below is a mock up of the code.

```
resp, err := http.Client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
lr := io.LimitReader(resp.Body, 1e+6)
b := make([]byte, 1e+6)
_, err := lmtdR.Read(b)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err

}
```

The above fails. However if I do this....

```
resp, err := http.Client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
lr := io.LimitReader(resp.Body, 1e+6)
bdy, err := ioutil.ReadAll(lr)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err

}
```

This works. So I have a solution, but really I want to know what I was doing wrong in the first example I gave. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Read` returns `io.EOF` when it reaches the end of the stream. That's not failing, that's how reading works. Use the latter version, since you don't need to allocate the entire slice when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Always start with the docs.

The difference is in the semantics:

`io.Reader.Read`:

> `~$ go doc io.Reader`
>
> ```golang
> package io // import "io"
>
> type Reader interface {
>     Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
> }
> ```
>
> `Reader` is the interface that wraps the basic `Read` method.
>
> `Read` reads up to `len(p)` bytes into `p`.
>   It returns the number of bytes read (`0 <= n <= len(p)`) and any error encountered.
>   Even if `Read` returns `n < len(p)`,
>   it may use all of `p` as scratch space during the call. If some data is
>   available but not `len(p)` bytes, Read conventionally returns what is
>   available instead of waiting for more.
>
> When `Read` encounters an error or end-of-file condition after successfully
>   reading `n > 0` bytes, it returns the number of bytes read.
>   It may return the (non-nil) error from the same call
>   or return the error (and `n == 0`) from a subsequent call.
>   An instance of this general case is that a `Reader` returning
>   a non-zero number of bytes at the end of the input stream may return either
>   `err == EOF` or `err == nil`. The next `Read` should return `0, EOF`.

`io/ioutil.ReadAll`:

> `~$ go doc ioutil.ReadAll`
>
> ```golang
> package ioutil // import "io/ioutil"
>
> func ReadAll(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error)
> ```
>
> `ReadAll` reads from `r` until an error or `EOF` and returns the data it read.
>   A successful call returns `err == nil`, not `err == EOF`.
>   Because `ReadAll` is defined to read from src until `EOF`,
>   it does not treat an `EOF` from `Read` as an error to be reported.

Comment: I must have read the docs about a hundred times....However your explanation made it crystallize for me. Like i said, obvious :)  Thank you!

Comment: @FailOver, BTW don't underestimate the availability of the source code ;-) Quite often, it helps to peer into the implementation. In the docs at <https://golang.org/pkg/>, the sources are available right form the documentation page. I mean, it may be of interest for you to look just how `io/ioutil.ReadAll` is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the doc of [`Reader.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader):

> Read **reads up to len(p) bytes** into p.

There is no guarantee that `Read()` will fill the passed slice even if there is enough data in its source. Implementations are free to read fewer bytes and return "early", typically if reading more would block. If by any chance `Read()` reads "everything" from its source, it may return EOF to signal no more data could be read. This is what you experienced.

[`ioutil.ReadAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) on the other hand guarantees it keeps reading or waiting until the reader returns an error or reports EOF. Also note that if the source reader is read until EOF, `ioutil.ReadAll()` will not return EOF but `nil` error, because reading until EOF is not considered an error (but success) in case of `ReadAll()`.